# XML parsing in C#. Issue with Descendants

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmlreader

I have an XML string that needs parsing.

Code looks as below:

```
inputXML = "<elementList xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">
            <NodePrime>
                <Node>
                     <NodeA>1</NodeA>
                     <NodeB>2</NodeB>
                </Node>
                <Node>
                     <NodeA>3</NodeA>
                     <NodeB>4</NodeB>
                </Node>
             </NodePrime>
             </elementList>";

var ItemList = new List<ItemList>();
using(XmlReader Reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(inputXML)))
{
     Reader.read();
     var doc = XDocument.Load(Reader);
     var xmlnode = doc.Descendants("Node");
     foreach(var item in xmlHeirarchy)
     {
         var ListA = new ItemList
         {
             itemA = item.Element("NodeA").Value;
             itemB = item.Element("NodeB").Value;
         };
         ItemList.Add(ListA );
     }
}
```

My issue is with the doc.Descendants as my xmlnode returns empty.

Please let me know what is it that I am doing wrong and the best way to do it.

Comment: xmlHeirarchy -> xmlnode. What is this `Reader.read();`?

Comment: The code works fine apart from some typos. Are you sure this is your real code? Is `inputXML` hard coded?

Comment: try something like doc.Root.Element("NodePrime").Elements().Descendants("Node")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `XDocument.Parse()` to populate `XDocument` from string, which is simpler than your current approach. Then `doc.Descendants("Node")` should've worked as demonstrated below :

```
var inputXML = @"<elementList xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
    <NodePrime>
        <Node>
             <NodeA>1</NodeA>
             <NodeB>2</NodeB>
        </Node>
        <Node>
             <NodeA>3</NodeA>
             <NodeB>4</NodeB>
        </Node>
     </NodePrime>
     </elementList>";

var ItemList = new List<ItemList>();
var doc = XDocument.Parse(inputXML);
var xmlnode = doc.Descendants("Node");
foreach(var item in xmlnode)
{
    var ListA = new ItemList
    {
        itemA = item.Element("NodeA").Value,
        itemB = item.Element("NodeB").Value
    };
    ItemList.Add(ListA );
}
Console.WriteLine(ItemList.Count());
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LIEfwo)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large file this is how I like doing it.  Using XmlTextReader uses less memory than XmlReader.  Only difference is XmlReader allows moving backwards in Xml while XmlTextReader is for forwarding only

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string inputXML = "<elementList xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">" +
                            "<NodePrime>" +
                                "<Node>" +
                                     "<NodeA>1</NodeA>" +
                                     "<NodeB>2</NodeB>" +
                                "</Node>" +
                                "<Node>" +
                                     "<NodeA>3</NodeA>" +
                                     "<NodeB>4</NodeB>" +
                                "</Node>" +
                             "</NodePrime>" +
                        "</elementList>";
            StringReader sReader = new StringReader(inputXML);
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(sReader);
            List<ItemList> itemList = new List<ItemList>();
            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.Name != "Node")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("Node");
                }
                if(!reader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement node = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                    itemList.Add(new ItemList() {
                       itemA = (int)node.Element("NodeA"),
                       itemB = (int)node.Element("NodeB")
                    });
                }
            }

        }
    }
    public class ItemList
    {
        public int itemA { get; set; }
        public int itemB { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `XmlTextReader` *is* an `XmlReader` and both allow forward-only access. Since .NET 2.0, Microsoft [guidance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader(v=vs.110).aspx) is **not** to use `XmlTextReader`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I see that the main problem is my XML string. It has a lot of garbage characters. I guess i will need to figure out a way to clean up my XML string.

Comment: I broke your string into lines to reduce the number of non-printable characters.